# Bring only necessary columns when left join

Tags: r, dplyr

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUSMf.png)

I would like to bring columns written in select(~~~) but when I run this code, all the columns in the accountmaster are brought. Is there any way to bring only necessary columns when left join?

My code is below.

```
accountuniverse <- union(subset(accountmaster, select = c("acctCD")),
                         subset(Sales2016, select = c("acctCD")),
                         subset(Sales2017, select = c("acctCD")),
                         subset(Sales2018, select = c("acctCD")),
                         subset(Sales2019, select = c("acctCD"))) %>% 
  left_join(accountmaster, %>% select(Acctname,DistrictCD,TerritoryCD,PostCD,Address, Acctclassificationname,Accttypename), by=c("acctCD"))
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Put select after join, something like: `left_join(..) %>% select(...)`. Improve your post, add example data and code as text - not image.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I revised my code as above, but red underline pops up under %>%.... Could you let me know why this happens?

Comment: Is the comma after "accountmaster" a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, something like this should work:

```
accountuniverse <- union(subset(accountmaster, select = c("acctCD")),
                         subset(Sales2016, select = c("acctCD")),
                         subset(Sales2017, select = c("acctCD")),
                         subset(Sales2018, select = c("acctCD")),
                         subset(Sales2019, select = c("acctCD"))) %>% 
  left_join(accountmaster, by = "acctCD") %>%
  select(Acctname, DistrictCD, TerritoryCD, PostCD, Address,
         Acctclassificationname, Accttypename))
```

**Note:** It is best to stick with one paradigm, either base or tidy.